# Unhandled exception... Access violation writing location

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to write a program that multiplies two arrays using double pointers. My code so far is:

```
        #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    //multiplies two matrices A(mxl) and B(lxn) to produce C(mxn)

    int m,l,n;
    int **A, **B, **C;

void main(void)
{
```

...user inputs m,l,n and allocates memory like this.

```
int i, j;

//creates a new mxl array   
A= (int**) new int*[m];
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        A[i]=new int[l];
    }

//creates a lxn array
B = (int**) new int*[l];
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        B[i]=new int[n];
    }

//creates a mxn array
C = (int**) new int*[m];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        C[i]=new int[n];
    }

int sum = 0;
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++)
        {
            sum =+ A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
    }
      //cout<sum<<"\t";
```

so far everything works fine. If I change this to just cout 'sum' then it returns all the correct elements of the array in the right order; it's when I try to put this value into the array that it returns an error message.

```
    C[i][j]=sum; 
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's a much better way to multiply matrices together but I'm much more interested in knowing why this particular piece of code doesn't work; it looks very simple and I can't see where the error is coming from.

Comment: please post a complete program that demonstrates the problem

Comment: This is most likely an error when allocating memory for C. Double-check that you have the right dimensions for when creating C.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show the allocations for `B` and `C`? Since this is array multiplication, `A` is `m*l`, `B` is `l*n`, and `C` must be `m*n`.

Comment: Assuming that the last two pieces of code are a single block in your program, only split up here, , it could be because `j` is out of scope.

Comment: The C array is allocated

Comment: @MatthewParker: Sure, but HOW is it allocated? My suspicion is that you got the dimensions wrong (i.e. you made a typo and put an 'm' where you should have an 'n' or something similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your update you added this code:

```
C = (int**) new int*[m];
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    C[i]=new int[n];
}
```

The loop condition is incorrect. Instead of `i<n` you need `i<m`.

Your multiplication loop looks like this:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++)
        {
            sum =+ A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
    }
    C[i][j]=sum; 
}
```

The assignment `C[i][j]` is in the wrong block–the `[j]` array access is out-of-bounds.

It should be like this:

```
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        sum = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++)
        {
            sum =+ A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j]=sum; 
    }
}
```

Note that I have initialised `sum` to 0 every time a new `j` loop is started. That corrects another error in your code.

It would be a lot better if you declared the variables with the tightest scope possible. Like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<l;k++)
        {
            sum =+ A[i][k]*B[k][j];
        }
        C[i][j]=sum; 
    }
}
```

Had you done that the compiler would have rejected your original placement of the assignment to `C[i][j]`.

Your `main` function should be declared like this:

```
int main()
```

and you should return a value from your `main()`.

Comment: I've changed the code to that and it returns the same error message.

Comment: You didn't show the code that allocated `B` and `C` so do check that you correctly allocated l×n and m×n matrices respectively.

Comment: Yup, you allocated `C` incorrectly. I think we've got all the errors now.

Comment: int main() is the only function in c++ that don't require a return statment.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj OK, but it's still worth being explicit in my opinion.

Comment: @MatthewParker Thanks for the accept and well done for your first question. You responded very well to requests for more information.